# jhipster yarn start command

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg

when i run yarn start command 
the error log generate is:

```
 yosay@^1.0.0, yosay@^1.0.2:
    version "1.2.1"
    resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/yosay/-/yosay-1.2.1.tgz#9466ef969830e85b474e267b50f7688693ed3b5b"
    dependencies:
      ansi-regex "^2.0.0"
      ansi-styles "^2.0.0"
      chalk "^1.0.0"
      cli-boxes "^1.0.0"
      pad-component "0.0.1"
      repeating "^2.0.0"
      string-width "^1.0.0"
      strip-ansi "^3.0.0"
      taketalk "^1.0.0"
      wrap-ansi "^2.0.0"

  zone.js@0.8.20:
    version "0.8.20"
    resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.8.20.tgz#a218c48db09464b19ff6fc8f0d4bb5b1046e185d"

Trace: 
  Error: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  Arguments: /d /s /c yarn run webpack:dev
  Directory: D:\JhSocietyAlekha
  Output:

      at ProcessTermError.MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:186:110)
      at new ProcessTermError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:226:113)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:30281:17)
      at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of yarn you are using? You could be affected by: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5481. Also, I've had many issues using yarn on Windows. I would recommend using npm instead.